# trouble with xml transformation

Tags: xslt, text, transformation, matching

I have an xml that looks something like this

```
<para>
   text text text
   <b>text</b> text text <i>text</i>
</para>
```

the objective is to convert this to mediaWiki formatting with ''' for a bold font and so on.

when I write a transformation for this the template match ignores all the text inside the `<para>` tag and only the the `<b>`s and the `<i>`s are converted. i need help.

update: here is what i have tried so far:

this is what i have tried so far.

```
<xsl:template match="para">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
<xsl:text>'''</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')" disable-output-escaping="no"/><xsl:text>'''</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
<xsl:text>''</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')" disable-output-escaping="no"/><xsl:text>''</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

this is what I used when i tried the text() function.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
</xsl:template>
```

--update--
in order to not lose the spaces before and after the text block and the bold and italics flags we can also check for spaces before and after the text.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="originalText" select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with($originalText,' ')">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" disable-output-escaping="no"/>
    <xsl:if test="ends-with($originalText,' ')">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: you'll need to show us your XSLT code if you want help with it.

Comment: share with us what you have already tried ?

Comment: text() node will give you the text inside a particular element. Have you tried that?

Comment: this is what i have tried so far.

<xsl:template match="para">
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
<xsl:text>'''</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')" disable-output-escaping="no"/><xsl:text>'''</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="i">
<xsl:text>''</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')" disable-output-escaping="no"/><xsl:text>''</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Please edit your question and put this code there...and please format it. thanks.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for explanation of the problem and for an easy solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I write a transformation for this
>   the template match ignores all the
>   text inside the  tag and only
>   the the `<b>`s and the `<i>`s are
>   converted. i need help.
>
> update: here is what i have tried so
>   far:
>
> this is what i have tried so far.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="para">  
>   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>  
> </xsl:template>
> ```

Your problem is exactly in this template. Your codes ignores anything else except element - children. the `*` abbreviation stands for `child::element()`. Thus the text-nodes children of `para` aren't processed at all.

**Solution**:

Simply remove the above template. Then the built-in XSLT template for element nodes will be selected to process the `para` element. All it does is `<xsl:apply-templates/>` and this is an abbreviation for `<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()"/>`. This applies templates for every child node (of any type, including text nodes). When the text-node children of `para` are processed, the built-in XSLT template for text node is selected -- all it does is to copy the text as is.

**The transformation now becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="b">
        <xsl:text>'''</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')"/>
        <xsl:text>'''</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="i">
        <xsl:text>''</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(replace(.,'\s+$',''),'^\s+','')" />
        <xsl:text>''</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<para>
   text text text
   <b>text</b> text text <i>text</i>
</para>
```

**the result now includes the text node children of** `para`:

```
   text text text
   '''text''' text text ''text''
```

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Good solution. But I think that there would be a better pattern for those `fn:replace` (same from the question, of course). Maybe `replace(.,'^\s*(.)\s*$','$1')`. Or, if there is not going to be new lines to preserve, just `normalize-space(.)`

Comment: @Alejandro: You may be right, I didn't delve deeper in the code -- just explained and solved the *main problem* -- and the OP is happy.

Comment: @Alejandro: good observation. it might also be a good idea to check for a space before/after `<b>` or `<i>` to account for something like `<b>text </b>text` or `text<i> text</i>`. This has nothing to do with the original question, but it's still fun to think about.

Comment: thats a great idea guys I used normalize-space(.) and checked for spaces before and after in the match text and the bold and italics tempaltes the transformations are even more accurate now .editing the post with the updated code might be useful for others

Comment: @Prithwin: Glad you found this answer great. At SO the gratitude and appreciation are shown by accepting the answer (just click on the check mark left to the answer) :)

Comment: i did do that earlier but i guess I must have missed the check mark :).. doin it again.